# OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ksize.width > ...... for GaussianBlur

Tags: java, opencv, gaussian

when I call Imgproc.GaussianBlur(dst, dst ,new Size(3,3),1); in my application it works perfectly fine. As soon as I increase the kernel size to new Size(4,4) or else I get an

> ```
> OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (ksize.width > 0 && ksize.width % 2 == 1 && ksize.height > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1) in cv::createGaussianFilter, file
> ```
>
> ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\smooth.cpp, line 816
>       Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: cv::Exception: ........\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\smooth.cpp:816:
>   error: (-215) ksize.width > 0 && ksize.width % 2 == 1 && ksize.height
>
> > 0 && ksize.height % 2 == 1 in function cv::createGaussianFilter
> >         ]
> >           at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.GaussianBlur_1(Native Method)
> >           at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.GaussianBlur(Imgproc.java:533)

Can please someone put me on the right track for this? I have no idea where/what to look for this.

Thx.

Comment: @berak! Thx, you're right. Reading does help sometimes....

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As I understood from the trace, you are only allowed to use `new Size(x,y)` where `x` and `y` are odd

Comment: in other words: kernel size must be odd.

Comment: Got same problem when i gave new Size(0,0), resolved it by making it only positive numbers